# Adding an attribute to a Telerik RadTextBox

Tags: c#, .net, telerik, radtextbox

I'm trying to get a hold of an attribute I've created on a Telerik RadTextBox in the code behind of a click event. I've seen it solved in Javascript, but not the .cs/.vb file. Hopefully my code will explain it better:
HTML:

```
<telerik:RadTextBox runat="server" ID="rdtTest" measurement-type="3" />
```

Code behind:

```
    protected void btnSave_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        RadTextBox rdtTest= (RadTextBox)item.FindControl("rdtTest");
        string m = rdtHead.Attributes("measurement-type");
    }
```

Visual Studio doesn't think that the Telerik RadTextBox can have an "attributes" method. Am I doing something wrong, or is it not supported in Telerik?

Comment: If you ask a vague question, you’ll get a vague answer. But if you give us details and context, we can provide a useful answer.

Comment: Your edited question makes more sense

Comment: I had accidentally submitted the question before it was finished, just a novice user error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this code

```
<telerik:RadTextBox ID="RadTextBox1" runat="server" />
```

In your code behind

```
var result = RadTextBox1.Attributes["yourKeyOfAttribute"];
```

Comment: That's correct and working now, I was using the wrong brackets altogether. Too early on a Monday... Thanks Candie

Comment: I'am happy to help you loxdog